# Data for an image file is being sent from ajax to php script but I cant figure out how to access it

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

Ajax that sends data to php script

```js
$(function () {
    $('#create_article').bind('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const file_data = $('#file').prop('files')[0];   
        const data = $('#create').serializeArray();

        data.push({name: "file_name", value: file_data.name}, {name: "file", value: file_data});
        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../scripts/create.php',
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function () {location.reload()}
        });
        alert('Article Created!');
    });
});
```

What `data` looks like: [image: Text]

PHP script

```php
$title = $_POST["title"];
$content = $_POST["content"];
$image_name = $_POST["file_name"];
$image = $_POST["file"];

$target_dir = "../blog_images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . $image_name;

move_uploaded_file($image, $target_file);

$sql = "INSERT INTO articles (title, content, image) VALUES ('$title', '$content', '$image_name');";
$result = $conn-> query($sql);
```

Html form that triggers the ajax script

```html
                <form id="create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <h1>Create an Article</h1><br>
                    <textarea name="title" class="title" rows="1" cols="20" placeholder="Article Title" required></textarea><br>
                    <textarea name="content" class="content" rows="10" cols="20" placeholder="Article Content" required></textarea><br>
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" required><br>

                    <input type="button" id="create_article" value="Create">
                </form>
```